# How to refactor this code?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Lately I have started to learn about refactoring code. How can i refactor this code. Where sould I start?

```
var activeNumber = [
    { name: 'no 1' },
    { name: 'no 2' },
    { name: 'no 11' },
    { name: 'no 3' },
    { name: 'no 10' }
];

var numberRe = new RegExp('\\d+');

var getCustomNumber = function () {
    var top = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < activeNumber.length; i++) {
        var present = numberRe.exec(activeNumber[i].name);
        if (present) {
            var neno = parseInt(present[0]);
            if (!isNaN(neno) && neno > top) {
                top = neno;
            }
        }
    }
    return top;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to find the max(highest) number within `name` property among list of objects.
Use the following optimized approach:

```js
var activeNumber = [
  {name: 'no 1'},
  {name: 'no 2'},
  {name: 'no 11'},
  {name: 'no 3'},
  {name: 'no 10'}
];

var getMaxNumber = function(arr) {
  var top = 0, items = [];
  if (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length === 0) return top;

  arr.forEach(function(o) {
    num = o.name.match(/\d+/);   // finds matches for a number in 'name' property
    if (num) items.push(num);
  });

  return Math.max.apply(null, items);   // gets the maximum value of the list
}

console.log(getMaxNumber(activeNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getCustomerNumber = function (custNumber) {
    var present = numberRe.exec(custNumber);
    if (present) {
        return parseInt(present[0]);
    }
    return -1;
};

var getAllCustomerNumbers = function (customers) {
    var top = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        var neno = getCustomerNumber(customers[i].name);
        if (!isNaN(neno) && neno > top) {
            top = neno;
        }
    }
    return top;
};
```

I hope I haven't done any mistake.

A simple rule is to create pieces of code that do one thing only. In the above example, one function is responsible for extracting the number from a string with the regular expression i.e. `getCustomerNumber` and another is to iterate over a number of customers and extract their numbers.

Also, it's useful to pass as arguments of your function all of your dependencies in this case `customers` or `custNumber`, the reason for that is that you can make your code testable (specifically unit testable) since you pass everything it needs to run.